# Construir sentencias sql correctamente en Java para evitar Inyección sql y ponerlo en un cursor

Tags: java, android, cursor, inyección-sql

Me asignaron arreglar un proyecto Android, y el gran problema es que todas las consultas sql hacia sqlite están de este modo

```
String  where = " nombre = '" + txt_nombre.getText().toString().trim()+"'"

Sring sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLA1 WHERE " + where + " ; ";

Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
return mCursor;
```

Como sabrán esto ocasiona muchos errores..  si es que se ingresa en

```
txt_nombre = ‘se introduce’’;
```

da error

**¿cuál es la mejor forma de poder solucionar esto?**  (Es todo un proyecto entero)

**ademas me solicitan que siga usando Cursores.**

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
 String sql = " SELECT *  FROM tabla1 "  ;
 List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();


 sql += String.format(" where %s  LIKE ? ", "tabla1.descrip" );
 args.add('%' + txt1.getText().toString() + '%');


 String[] queryArgs = args.toArray( new String[args.size()]);

Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(strSQL, queryArgs );
```

Comment: Reemplaza esos caracteres o comillas sencilla por doble.

Comment: Si es que haz encontrado la solución a tu pregunta dentro de una de las respuestas de la misma, debes de marcarla como aceptada, de lo contrario, si es que haz encontrado la respuesta por ti mismo, por favor si es que desean comparte lo que haz hecho respondiendo a tu misma pregunta, no debes de agregar SOLUCIONADO al título, saludos!

Comment: Listo Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para próximas preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre un paso similar al PreparedStatement  pero este usa el rawQwuey  y que devuelve el resultado en un CURSOR.

este es un ejemplo

```
 String sql = " SELECT *  FROM tabla1 "  ;  List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();


 sql += String.format(" where %s  LIKE ? ", "tabla1.descrip" );  args.add('%' + txt1.getText().toString() + '%');


 String[] queryArgs = args.toArray( new String[args.size()]);

Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(strSQL, queryArgs );
```

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer operaciones de escritura se usa preparedStatement, lo que hay hacer es escribir la query con '?' donde van los parámetros. Por ej (del tutorial):

```
String updateString = "update COFFEES set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

Y luego vas asignando los valores:

```
updateSales.setInt(1, 125);
updateSales.setString(2, "cappuccino");
```

Y al final lo ejecutas (en este caso un update):

```
updateSales.executeUpdate();
```

Para una query select sería análogo, ejecutando otro método:

```
String selectString = "select SALES from COFFEES where COF_NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement selectSales = con.prepareStatement(selectString);
selectSales.setString(1, "cappuccino");
```

ejecutando otro método (executeQuery):

```
ResultSet result = updateSales.executeQuery();
```

El objeto ResultSet (result) es lo que necesitas para extraer los datos (el equivalente al cursor)

La info completa la puedes ver en el tutorial oficial de oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#cursors

Comment: perfecto.. pero resulta que al final los resultados los pone en cursores.. y me piden que siga usando cursores..   se puede pasar a un Cursor?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para explicar como extraer el cursor. El resulSet tiene los métodos next, previous, first, last etc ....
No olvides cerrarlos (con close())

Comment: Encontré como hacerlo..  ya edite la pregunta. y añadí la solución . muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta si lo que se quiere es evitar la Inyeccion de SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes reemplazar los caracteres por comillas dobles
 para que puedas realizar correctamente tu consulta:

```
  where = where.replace("‘", "''").replace("’","''").replace("'","''");
```

de esta forma crearías correctamente tu query y obtendrás tu cursor.

```
String  where = " nombre = '" + txt_nombre.getText().toString().trim()+"'"

where = where.replace("‘", "''").replace("’","''").replace("'","''");

Sring sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLA1 WHERE " + where + " ; ";

Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
return mCursor;
```